# Process cannot access the file used by another process minted

Tags: luatex, minted, auxiliary-files

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\mintinline{Java}{int a = b;}
\end{document}
```

I have saved my mwe with the name mwe.tex. When I compile it with:

```
lualatex.exe --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "mwe".tex
```

It says (among other stuff):

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./_minted-mwe/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (./_minted-mwe/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-mwe/B6F14A365A3CA2B63619D9B3E09027C5EA189C4E0332DB1C2B1AA5FF2D64DFC0
.pygtex) [1{C:/Users/ben/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./mwe.aux)C:\Users\ben\Downloads\stackx\mwe.pyg
Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess
 verwendet wird.
```

The translation for the last line is:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

This does not happen with with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I don't see that when I try, but could you try the patch here https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/pull/7/files